# MVC4 published to IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I have an MVC4 application that works fine from Visual Studio, but when I built it to local IIS or publish it to remote IIS (7.5 both) I get 403 error.

Is there some setting I am missing in IIS to run MVC? (I run PHP Zend 2 and Symphony apps on the server with no problem)

Comment: So you have IIS and Apache running on parallel ?

Comment: No. I run the PHP apps on IIS (replacing the `.htaccess` files with URL Rewrite `web.config` files.

Comment: Ok...this is your first .net deployment on your actual development environment?

Comment: First MVC deployment. There are a couple of asp.net apps.

Answer (score 0):

403 is an Access Denied.  Do you have authentication scheme in your application or is it supposed to be anonymous access?  If you want anonymous access, open IIS manager and go to your website.  Under the IIS section, open the Authentication item and make sure anonymous authentication is enabled.  Another spot to check is under the ASP.NET section, make sure there is not a deny under the .NET authorization section.

Comment: the error I'm getting is about listing the contents of the directory. The routing doesn't seem to be working. I have done this before on other servers with no additional setup. This server was originally built to house PHP apps and have slowly come to be a .net server as well. My guess is that the settings needed to run PHP are incompatible with .net mvc (I hope this isn't the case) - but as I said, it runs fine in VS... it just won't publish.

Comment: This is on a website that is not housing a PHP app correct?  MVC installed on the server and the app pool for the site running on a .NET 4.0?

Comment: Well, that is what I will check next. It isn't my server! (hehe) I assumed since I was commissioned to develop an MVC app that the server was ready for it... damn me for assuming, I guess.

Comment: Probably MVC not installed then, you can get the server installer here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683

Answer (score 0):

The solution? Adding this line to my web.config

`<system.Webserver>`

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>`

Seems like that would be documented somewhere... or maybe INCLUDED in the scaffolding.
Just a thought.